# Convert epoch to date using DATEADD

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dateadd, json-extract

I explored a lot. I am using this to convert epoch time to date:

```
CASE 
  WHEN json_extract_path_text(cli, 'pickupDate') IS NULL OR json_extract_path_text(cli, 'pickupDate') = '' 
  THEN DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(bigint, json_extract_path_text(cli, 'pickupTime')), '1970-1-1'), '1970-1-1' ) 
  ELSE json_extract_path_text(cli, 'pickupDate') 
END AS "Start Date"
```

To give little context, if the key 'pickupDate' in json is not present, i need to make use of this key 'pickUpTime' to get the value. When i do this, i get this error:

> Invalid operation: CASE types text and timestamp without time zone cannot be matched;
>       1 statement failed.

Can someone help me out here? How do we specify timezone or if there is another way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it down into parts to see where the issue could be.

Does this expression work?

```
DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(bigint, json_extract_path_text(cli, 'pickupTime')),'1970-1-1')
```

If it does, then try to find the resulting data types of the previous expression and this one to see if they match: `json_extract_path_text(cli, 'pickupDate')`

If that works, try explicitly declaring `DATE '1970-1-1'` as a date using the `DATE` prefix.

Also, not sure but it looks like there's an extra parentheses in the expression you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear - you can't return two incompatible data types from a case expression.

The case expression must return compatible data types from all it's branches, so it's not enough to simply read the text from the josn in the `else` part, you still need to convert it to `datetime`.
I'm not familiar with the specifics of Amazon redshift but I'm guessing you need `convert`